# How to make two jquery function can work together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have develop a form and have two function one is to choose the date using datepicker another function is use to redirect the page to the here using ajax function.Now the problem is only the ajax function can working at here if i include the jquery 2.1.1 ,if i remove the 2.1.1 then only the datepicker can function.Does anyone have any idea about how to solve this jquery problem ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
 
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script type="text/javascript">
 

$(function() {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            },
            beforeShow : function(input, inst) {
                var datestr;
                if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                    year = datestr.substring(datestr.length-4, datestr.length);
                    month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length-5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNamesShort'));
                    $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                }
            }
        });
    });
 
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){   
  $('.reveal').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.page').load(link);
    });

});
</script>


</head>
   <style>
  .ui-datepicker-calendar {
        display: none;
        }
</style>
 <header>
            
      
 </header>

<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="homepage.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Sales Report</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="reveal" href="table.html">Monthly Sales by Customer Category</a>
      <a class="reveal" href="Login1.html">Monthly Sales by Customer Category</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
   
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
 <label for="startDate">Date :</label>
    <input type="text" class="date-picker" />

<div class ="page">

 
  </div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason you are using such anchient jQuery and jQuery UI? Not sure which version of jQuery is required to run jQuery UI 1.7.2, might be it needs newer jQuery than the one you are using.

Comment: i'm using that ancient jquery is because of the datepicker function need it,the function i founded online is quite useful but it seems cannot be work in the latest jquery function .i have try to make it as one but only the ajax function can work

Comment: What function are you talking about?

Comment: the $('.date-picker').datepicker function

Comment: Datepicker has been part of the jQuery UI forever and is [still](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), this can not be the reason you are using so old jQuery UI and jQuery... I don't understand what is your problem, use newer versions and give it a try.